# A reference question on the Dedekind zeta function and other L-functions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, zeta-functions, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

On page 501 in the following ICM1983 conference proceeding

https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1983.1/ICM1983.1.ocr.pdf

you will find a conjecture on the L-function $L(X,s)$ of an arithmetic scheme $X/\mathbb{Z}$.
We define the L-function $L(X,s)$ as follows:

$$C1.\text{  }L(X,s):= \prod_{x\in X^{cl}}\frac{1}{1-N(x)^{-s}}$$

where $x\in X$ is a closed point and $N(x)$ is the number of elements in the residue field of $x$. The function $L(X,s)$ generalize the Riemann zeta function and is conjectured to satisfy the following formula (Conjecture 2.2.iii):

$$C3.\text{ } ord_{s=j}(L(X,s))= \chi(X,j)$$

where $\chi(X,j)$ is the $j$'th Euler characteristic of $X$.

**Example:** If $E^*$ is an elliptic curve over a number field with $E/S$ its corresponding Neron model, it follows the conjecture

$$C_{ell}.\text{ } ord_{s=1}(L(E,s))=\chi(E,1)$$

is a K-theoretic version of the BSD conjecture for $E^*$.

On page 501 in the paper on the above link the author mentions the following conjecture (this is a translation):

**Conjecture 1:** If $X$ is of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ it follows the function $L(X,s)$ has an analytic continuation to the complex plane.

**Question:** What is known on Conjecture 1?

**Example.** If $K$ is a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $S:=Spec(\mathcal{O}_K)$ it follows $L(S,s)$ is the Dedekind zeta function of $K$. Is Conjecture 1 known for $L(S,s)$? I ask for references?

**Note:** The "L-function" $L(X,s)$ defined in C1 is also referred to as the "zeta function" of $X$, written $\zeta_X(s)$.

Another reference is a paper of Serre in

"Arithmetical Algebraic Geometry": Proceedings of a Conference Held at Purdue University December 5-7, 1963 O F G Schilling

Serre uses "zeta function" and "L-function" for the function $L(X,s)$ from C1.

**Example:** Assume $\pi: X \rightarrow S$ where $S:=Spec(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and $K$ is a number field, and $X_t:=\pi^{-1}(t)$ with $t\in S^{cl}$ a closed point. Assume $X_t$ is a smooth projective scheme of finite type over $\kappa(t)$ for any $t$. It follows there is a product formula

$$L(X,s)=\prod_{t\in S^{cl}} L(X_t,s)$$

and $L(X_t,s)$ is a "rational function" in the following sense: If $Z(X_t,T)$ is the Weil zeta function of $X_t$ it follows

$$L(X_t,s)= Z(X_t,q^{-s})$$

where $q:=\#\kappa(t)$ is the number of elements in $\kappa(t)$. Hence $L(X,s)$ is an "infinite product of Weil zeta functions" which are known to be rational functions by the work of Dwork/Grothendieck/Artin...

Comment: This is still a huge topic of research, and underlines much of the work in the Langlands program. For the Dedekind zeta function, the result goes back to Riemann (I think! He certainly handled the case $K = \mathbb Q$). The most enlightening proof is in Tate's thesis (which is published in Cassels and Frohlich) but you can find a proof in many number theory textbooks.

Comment: As to what's known in general: essentially the only method is to prove that $L(X, s)$ is also the $L$-function of an automorphic representation (i.e. a modularity theorem), where analytic continuation can be proved using analytic methods (Mellin transforms, etc). So, for example, the case where $X$ is a semistable elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ follows from the work of Wiles and Taylor-Wiles. Beyond that case, there are many examples where potential modularity has been proven (e.g. elliptic curves and abelian surfaces over tot. real fields), which is enough to prove meromorphic continuation.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Quite sure the analytic continuation of the Dedekind zeta function is due to Hecke. (the functional equation) is quite hard, like using most results in algebraic number theory and a bunch of analysis.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for that correction!

Comment: The vanishing of $\zeta_K(s)$ at integers is well-understood from the functional equation, there is no critical strip difficulty as in $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)/L(s,E)$ at $s=1$ for an elliptic curve. Also what you noted $L(X,s)$ is denoted $\zeta(X,s)$, the $L^i(X,s)$ are the [other Galois rep cohomology factors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308772/what-is-the-spectral-interpretation-of-the-arithmetic-zeta-function).

Comment: Are you saying that $C3$ for the Dedekind zeta function follows from the functional equation for the Dedekind zeta function?

Comment: By the way, for BSD specifically, Tate described it as "a remarkable conjecture, which relates the behaviour of a function L at a point where it is not known to be defined to the
order of a group that is not known to be finite." As of late 2018, we know that if $E$ is an elliptic curve over a CM field (or over a quadratic extension of a totally real field), the $L$-function has meromorphic continuation. Analytic continuation is known over $\mathbb Q$ and real quadratic fields. Over a general number field, the conjecture is completely open.

Comment: @reuns - In the case of an abelian variety $A^*$ over a number field $K$, you may construct the Neron model $A$ and its "L-function" (or "zeta function" as defined above). What type of product formula do you get in this case? You speak of "Galois cohomology factors" - how do you define these for an abelian variety and what is the relation with the above definition?

Comment: @reuns - you get two functions: The function $L(A,s)$ defined above and your function $\zeta_{A^*}(s)$ defined using the Galois cohomology of $A^*$. How are these related?